# Is there any alternative way to become polite to say this sentence?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In any educating video, in the end one can say "Let's maintain social distancing".

That's one way.

For some reason, I don't want to use **Let's**

And just saying "Maintain social distancing" isn't quite polite.

Is there any similar solution/phrase for the same?

Comment: Please maintain social distancing.

Comment: @WeatherVane Please don’t answer questions in comments.

Comment: Define "for some reason." Unless we know what your problem is with it (it sounds quite natural and polite to me), we can't possibly suggest alternatives that wouldn't be problematic.

Comment: @David That wasn't an answer. That was a short comment that would be make a very poor answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Don't forget** to maintain social distancing.

"Don't forget" implies that the audience already knows they're supposed to maintain social distancing, and is generally perceived as a polite reminder rather than an order.

Comment: Actually it perfectly answers. But is it possible to make it shorter?

Comment: How much shorter can it get? You could use "Try".

Comment: Some user also commented "Please". Is it also correct?

Comment: That still sounds a bit forceful to me. It's better than without it, but not as polite as "Let's".

Answer (score 1):

'Remember to maintain social distancing' 'Please remember to socially distance' or 'Please ensure social distancing'.

I have kept these deliberately short because of the feedback that 'Don't forget to maintain social distancing' might be too long.